# Showing thumbnail image from image data of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image

I have a json file with following thumbnail object structure.

```
  {
    "locations":{
      "test_1":{
        "tel":"+41 58 249 91 91",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "title":"Basel",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 3456",
        "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:56 GMT+0000",
        "id":"7a365fda-3e9b-be9e-0e91-a9b72856e6d6",
        "zip_city":"4002 Basel",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 91 23",
        "sort":"1",
        "maplocation":"47.549435,7.585241",
        "street":"Viaduktstrasse 42",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:29 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:58 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"ad388a5c-8638-4fed-a668-af2a9e1b173e",
                ":jcr:data":55007,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:30 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "bern":{
        "tel":"+41 58 249 76 00",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "title":"Bern",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 112",
        "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:56 GMT+0000",
        "id":"bfd2fff6-e769-6d2b-2722-9c09be415e10",
        "zip_city":"3073 Gümligen-Bern",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 76 17",
        "sort":"2",
        "maplocation":"46.93299,7.513097",
        "street":"Hofgut",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:40 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:58 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"7880b3ff-7d68-496f-a343-7fcc782eb0fd",
                ":jcr:data":61817,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:41 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "geneva":{
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "title":"Geneva",
        "tel":"+41 58 249 25 15",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 347",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:33:03 GMT+0000",
        "slingOldResourceType":"launchbase/components/launchbase/customerSpecificCode/__generic/",
        "id":"85ada88f-20c8-00ef-772d-9f040f978a7d",
        "zip_city":"1211 Geneva 13",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 73 13",
        "sort":"3",
        "maplocation":"Rue+de+Lyon+111,+1203+Genf,+Schweiz",
        "street":"Rue de Lyon 111",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:51 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:33:03 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"d2e9be65-cae3-47ff-bf7c-b4193c4cd48a",
                ":jcr:data":70181,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:52 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "lausanne":{
        "title":"Lausanne",
        "tel":"+41 58 249 45 55",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 6663",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:49:28 GMT+0000",
        "id":"8a954430-faff-1af6-9383-fce04e57ee80",
        "zip_city":"1002 Lausanne",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 45 65",
        "sort":"4",
        "maplocation":"46.518507,6.637137",
        "street":"Avenue du Théâtre 1",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:09 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:49:28 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"1f8bb242-c2d2-402a-9609-c2a1f8337522",
                ":jcr:data":60302,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:10 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "lucerne":{
        "title":"Lucerne",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "tel":"+41 58 249 38 38",
        "mode":"update",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:51:03 GMT+0000",
        "id":"a29e5fb0-5e6e-a774-86d6-c68f867efe80",
        "zip_city":"6003 Lucerne",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 38 88",
        "sort":"5",
        "maplocation":"47.047772,8.304472",
        "street":"Pilatusstrasse 41",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:19 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:51:03 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"4e70e476-65ed-481e-be26-64a5a241c6bc",
                ":jcr:data":61644,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:20 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "lugano":{
        "title":"Lugano",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "tel":"+41 58 249 32 32",
        "mode":"update",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:55:27 GMT+0000",
        "id":"1c056c0e-fa83-8ced-1084-ac159d6bf6db",
        "zip_city":"6900 Lugano",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 32 33",
        "sort":"6",
        "maplocation":"46.008073,8.959413",
        "street":"Via Balestra 33",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:29 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:55:27 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"33ca8dec-7d18-49e8-817f-95a1d663bdb2",
                ":jcr:data":67674,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:30 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "neuch_tel":{
        "tel":"+41 58 249 61 30",
        "title":"Neuchâtel",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 2572",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:57:06 GMT+0000",
        "slingOldResourceType":"launchbase/components/launchbase/customerSpecificCode/__generic/",
        "id":"9fce49b2-48dc-8bf0-541e-9b79b614ed8d",
        "zip_city":"2001 Neuchâtel",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 61 58",
        "sort":"7",
        "maplocation":"Rue+du+Seyon+1,+2000+Neuenburg,+Schweiz",
        "street":"Rue du Seyon 1",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:38 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:57:06 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"51b4d831-d1b1-44da-b1f0-f2d83f058a1e",
                ":jcr:data":64736,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:39 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "st_gallen":{
        "title":"St. Gallen",
        "tel":"+41 58 249 22 11",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 1142",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:57:53 GMT+0000",
        "id":"577b75ed-6c0e-7ea9-c158-6d10e2d85246",
        "zip_city":"9001 St. Gallen",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 22 12",
        "sort":"8",
        "maplocation":"47.420683,9.363352",
        "street":"Bogenstrasse 7",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:50 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:11:39 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"a01f593c-526c-48a3-88bb-562903999428",
                ":jcr:data":72246,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:51 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "zug":{
        "tel":"+41 58 249 74 74",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "title":"Zug",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 4427",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:13:45 GMT+0000",
        "id":"4be64252-a892-f5fc-2e45-e412df9542ac",
        "zip_city":"6304 Zug",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 50 00",
        "sort":"9",
        "maplocation":"47.176149,8.512084",
        "street":"Landis + Gyr-Strasse 1",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:30:01 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:13:45 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"cb2890d0-a8ba-45ec-b175-7b87f1597fa0",
                ":jcr:data":66838,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:30:02 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "zurich":{
        "title":"Zurich",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "tel":"+41 58 249 31 31",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 1872",
        "subtitle":"Head Office",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:15:12 GMT+0000",
        "id":"a76d54e2-5b40-e389-a134-8db5cd3ebd67",
        "zip_city":"8026 Zurich",
        "fax":"+41 58 249 44 06",
        "sort":"10",
        "maplocation":"47.375148,8.520173",
        "street":"Badenerstrasse 172",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:20 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:15:12 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"f90887d0-ef95-4841-992e-d94cfc7b90e8",
                ":jcr:data":70144,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:21 GMT+0000"
            }
        }
    },
    "schaan_liechtenstein":{
        "tel":"+423 237 70 40",
        "thumbnail.ext":"png",
        "title":"Schaan (LI)",
        "mode":"update",
        "pobox":"P.O. Box 342",
        "subtitle":"KPMG (Liechtenstein) AG",
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:16:40 GMT+0000",
        "id":"b57b76b9-4f8b-7fee-09fc-533e5b96015e",
        "zip_city":"LI-9494 Schaan",
        "fax":"+423 237 70 50",
        "sort":"11",
        "maplocation":"Landstrasse+99,+9494+Schaan,+Liechtenstein",
        "street":"Landstrasse 99",
        "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:29 GMT+0000",
        "thumbnail":{
            "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:16:40 GMT+0000",
            "jcr:content":{
                "jcr:uuid":"a8baee04-d0f4-4f2c-9cfb-e9299dc77406",
                ":jcr:data":58374,
                "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
                "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:30 GMT+0000"
            }
          }
        }

      }
  }
```

The thumbnail is placed in **images/locations/test_1/thumbnail**

I want to add the thumbnail as a source of an image while parsing the json.

```
        var content = '';

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("json/locations.json", function(json){
            console.log(json);
            $.each(json.locations, function(index){
                content = "<div class=\"location\">" +
                            "<div class=\"location-name\"><strong>" + json.locations[index].title + "</strong></div>" +
                            "<div class=\"location-desc\">" +
                                "<p>Als unternehmerisch denkende Berater und ausgewiesene Kenner der Wirtschaftsregion k�nnen wir Sie in Ihrer F�hrungsaufgabe mit rund 80 Mitarbeitenden unterst�tzen.</p>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"location-content\">" +
                                "<table>" +
                                    "<tr style=\"width: 100%\">" +
                                        "<td style=\"width: 50%\">" +
                                            "<img class=\"location-image\" style=\"width: 90%\" src=\"images/locations/"+ json.locations[index] + "/thumbnail." + json.locations[index].thumbnail.ext + "\" alt=\"\"/>" +
                                        "</td>" +
                                        "<td style=\"width: 50%\">" +
                                            "<div style=\"font-size: 12px\">" +
                                                "<div>" + json.locations[index].street + ", " + json.locations[index].pobox + ", " + json.locations[index].zip_city + "</div>" +
                                                "<div>Tel: " + json.locations[index].tel + "</div>" +
                                                "<div>Fax: " + json.locations[index].fax + "</div>" +
                                                "<div class=\"location-map\" onclick=\"initialize("+ json.locations[index].maplocation +");\">Auf Karte anzeigen</div>" +
                                            "</div>" +
                                        "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>" +
                                "</table>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>";
                $('.locations').append(content);     
                $(".location-map").click(function(){
                   $("#content-wrapper").css("display", "none");
                   $("#map-container").css("display", "block");
                   $("#map-canvas").css("display", "block");
                });
            });
        });

    });
```

How to modify the source of the image to show the thumbnail. I have seen some examples using data urls but couldn't figure out how to do it correctly. Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: What/where is your thumbnail name in your json object?

Comment: the thumbnail name is actually "thumbnail" as given in the thumbnail path. In json only the extension is given as "thumbnail.ext"

Comment: paste your JS/JQuery code here. It would be helpful to give you correct answer.

Comment: provided the complete json and js file

Comment: I think that `thumbnail.ext` reference to *images/locations/test_1/thumbnail/thumbnail/ext*. Try to change `thumbnail.ext` to `thumbnailExt` and call it like `json.locations[index].thumbnailExt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first change `thumbnail.ext` to `thumbnailExt` because `thumbnail.ext` reference to *"thumbnail": { ext: val }*.

Add array `var indexKey = [], i = 0;`

```
var content = '';

var indexKey = [], i = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("json/locations.json", function(json){

        for (var key in json.locations) {
                indexKey[indexKey.length] = key;
            }


        // console.log(json.locations);
        $.each(json.locations, function(index, value){

            content = "<div class=\"location\">" +
                        "<div class=\"location-name\"><strong>" + json.locations[index].title + "</strong></div>" +
                        "<div class=\"location-desc\">" +
                            "<p>Als unternehmerisch denkende Berater und ausgewiesene Kenner der Wirtschaftsregion k�nnen wir Sie in Ihrer F�hrungsaufgabe mit rund 80 Mitarbeitenden unterst�tzen.</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class=\"location-content\">" +
                            "<table>" +
                                "<tr style=\"width: 100%\">" +
                                    "<td style=\"width: 50%\">" +
                                        "<img class=\"location-image\" style=\"width: 90%\" src=\"images/locations/"+ indexKey[i] + "/thumbnail." + json.locations[index].thumbnailExt + "\" alt=\"\"/>" +
                                    "</td>" +
                                    "<td style=\"width: 50%\">" +
                                        "<div style=\"font-size: 12px\">" +
                                            "<div>" + json.locations[index].street + ", " + json.locations[index].pobox + ", " + json.locations[index].zip_city + "</div>" +
                                            "<div>Tel: " + json.locations[index].tel + "</div>" +
                                            "<div>Fax: " + json.locations[index].fax + "</div>" +
                                            "<div class=\"location-map\" onclick=\"initialize("+ json.locations[index].maplocation +");\">Auf Karte anzeigen</div>" +
                                        "</div>" +
                                    "</td>" +
                                "</tr>" +
                            "</table>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>";
                    i++;
            $('.locations').append(content);     
            $(".location-map").click(function(){
               $("#content-wrapper").css("display", "none");
               $("#map-container").css("display", "block");
               $("#map-canvas").css("display", "block");
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Note change to your structure.  We are adding keys to array and calling that key.

Here you go a JSON file.

```
{
"locations":{
  "test_1":{
    "tel":"+41 58 249 91 91",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "title":"Basel",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 3456",
    "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:56 GMT+0000",
    "id":"7a365fda-3e9b-be9e-0e91-a9b72856e6d6",
    "zip_city":"4002 Basel",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 91 23",
    "sort":"1",
    "maplocation":"47.549435,7.585241",
    "street":"Viaduktstrasse 42",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:29 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:58 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"ad388a5c-8638-4fed-a668-af2a9e1b173e",
            ":jcr:data":55007,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:30 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"bern":{
    "tel":"+41 58 249 76 00",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "title":"Bern",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 112",
    "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:56 GMT+0000",
    "id":"bfd2fff6-e769-6d2b-2722-9c09be415e10",
    "zip_city":"3073 Gümligen-Bern",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 76 17",
    "sort":"2",
    "maplocation":"46.93299,7.513097",
    "street":"Hofgut",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:40 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Tue Dec 17 2013 13:02:58 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"7880b3ff-7d68-496f-a343-7fcc782eb0fd",
            ":jcr:data":61817,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:41 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"geneva":{
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "title":"Geneva",
    "tel":"+41 58 249 25 15",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 347",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:33:03 GMT+0000",
    "slingOldResourceType":"launchbase/components/launchbase/customerSpecificCode/__generic/",
    "id":"85ada88f-20c8-00ef-772d-9f040f978a7d",
    "zip_city":"1211 Geneva 13",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 73 13",
    "sort":"3",
    "maplocation":"Rue+de+Lyon+111,+1203+Genf,+Schweiz",
    "street":"Rue de Lyon 111",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:51 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:33:03 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"d2e9be65-cae3-47ff-bf7c-b4193c4cd48a",
            ":jcr:data":70181,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:28:52 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"lausanne":{
    "title":"Lausanne",
    "tel":"+41 58 249 45 55",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 6663",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:49:28 GMT+0000",
    "id":"8a954430-faff-1af6-9383-fce04e57ee80",
    "zip_city":"1002 Lausanne",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 45 65",
    "sort":"4",
    "maplocation":"46.518507,6.637137",
    "street":"Avenue du Théâtre 1",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:09 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:49:28 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"1f8bb242-c2d2-402a-9609-c2a1f8337522",
            ":jcr:data":60302,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:10 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"lucerne":{
    "title":"Lucerne",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "tel":"+41 58 249 38 38",
    "mode":"update",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:51:03 GMT+0000",
    "id":"a29e5fb0-5e6e-a774-86d6-c68f867efe80",
    "zip_city":"6003 Lucerne",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 38 88",
    "sort":"5",
    "maplocation":"47.047772,8.304472",
    "street":"Pilatusstrasse 41",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:19 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:51:03 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"4e70e476-65ed-481e-be26-64a5a241c6bc",
            ":jcr:data":61644,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:20 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"lugano":{
    "title":"Lugano",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "tel":"+41 58 249 32 32",
    "mode":"update",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:55:27 GMT+0000",
    "id":"1c056c0e-fa83-8ced-1084-ac159d6bf6db",
    "zip_city":"6900 Lugano",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 32 33",
    "sort":"6",
    "maplocation":"46.008073,8.959413",
    "street":"Via Balestra 33",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:29 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:55:27 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"33ca8dec-7d18-49e8-817f-95a1d663bdb2",
            ":jcr:data":67674,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:30 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"neuch_tel":{
    "tel":"+41 58 249 61 30",
    "title":"Neuchâtel",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 2572",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:57:06 GMT+0000",
    "slingOldResourceType":"launchbase/components/launchbase/customerSpecificCode/__generic/",
    "id":"9fce49b2-48dc-8bf0-541e-9b79b614ed8d",
    "zip_city":"2001 Neuchâtel",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 61 58",
    "sort":"7",
    "maplocation":"Rue+du+Seyon+1,+2000+Neuenburg,+Schweiz",
    "street":"Rue du Seyon 1",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:38 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:57:06 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"51b4d831-d1b1-44da-b1f0-f2d83f058a1e",
            ":jcr:data":64736,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:39 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"st_gallen":{
    "title":"St. Gallen",
    "tel":"+41 58 249 22 11",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 1142",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 13:57:53 GMT+0000",
    "id":"577b75ed-6c0e-7ea9-c158-6d10e2d85246",
    "zip_city":"9001 St. Gallen",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 22 12",
    "sort":"8",
    "maplocation":"47.420683,9.363352",
    "street":"Bogenstrasse 7",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:50 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:11:39 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"a01f593c-526c-48a3-88bb-562903999428",
            ":jcr:data":72246,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:29:51 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"zug":{
    "tel":"+41 58 249 74 74",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "title":"Zug",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 4427",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:13:45 GMT+0000",
    "id":"4be64252-a892-f5fc-2e45-e412df9542ac",
    "zip_city":"6304 Zug",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 50 00",
    "sort":"9",
    "maplocation":"47.176149,8.512084",
    "street":"Landis + Gyr-Strasse 1",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:30:01 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:13:45 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"cb2890d0-a8ba-45ec-b175-7b87f1597fa0",
            ":jcr:data":66838,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:30:02 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"zurich":{
    "title":"Zurich",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "tel":"+41 58 249 31 31",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 1872",
    "subtitle":"Head Office",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:15:12 GMT+0000",
    "id":"a76d54e2-5b40-e389-a134-8db5cd3ebd67",
    "zip_city":"8026 Zurich",
    "fax":"+41 58 249 44 06",
    "sort":"10",
    "maplocation":"47.375148,8.520173",
    "street":"Badenerstrasse 172",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:20 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:15:12 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"f90887d0-ef95-4841-992e-d94cfc7b90e8",
            ":jcr:data":70144,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:21 GMT+0000"
        }
    }
},
"schaan_liechtenstein":{
    "tel":"+423 237 70 40",
    "thumbnailExt":"png",
    "title":"Schaan (LI)",
    "mode":"update",
    "pobox":"P.O. Box 342",
    "subtitle":"KPMG (Liechtenstein) AG",
    "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:16:40 GMT+0000",
    "id":"b57b76b9-4f8b-7fee-09fc-533e5b96015e",
    "zip_city":"LI-9494 Schaan",
    "fax":"+423 237 70 50",
    "sort":"11",
    "maplocation":"Landstrasse+99,+9494+Schaan,+Liechtenstein",
    "street":"Landstrasse 99",
    "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:29 GMT+0000",
    "thumbnail":{
        "jcr:created":"Thu Feb 13 2014 14:16:40 GMT+0000",
        "jcr:content":{
            "jcr:uuid":"a8baee04-d0f4-4f2c-9cfb-e9299dc77406",
            ":jcr:data":58374,
            "jcr:mimeType":"image/png",
            "jcr:lastModified":"Fri Nov 07 2014 17:31:30 GMT+0000"
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For JSON object like this i have upated my code only showing  the image rendering codes:

```
<div id="image-gallery">
</div>

<!--include the json file with relative path here by repacing the src of activity.jsonp script -->
<script src="~/Data/activity.jsonp"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       for (var prop in locations)
       {
           $("#image-gallery").append('<image src="~/images/"'+locations[prop]+"/thumbnail."+ prop["thumbnail.ext"] />');
       }      

});
</script>
```

Comment: He doesen't know key names. So if he want to implement this method, he will need to hardcode each of locations manualy.